# How to add textures to vertex buffer objects in OpenGL (2.1)

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, texture-mapping, texture2d

What is the correct way to texture map an object in OpenGL 2.1? At the moment I am performing the following steps but am unable to get the texture to appear correctly on the object.

1. Generate a buffer and store the ID
2. Bind the buffer
3. Upload the data to the buffer
4. Every time the object from the buffer is rendered:

   4.1. Enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` and `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY`

   4.2. Bind the texture then bind the buffer

   4.3 Setup `glTexCoordPointer` then setup `glVertexPointer`

   4.4 Use `glDrawArrays` to render the object

   4.5 Call `glFlush`

Code for creating the VBO:

```
GLuint flagVBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &flagVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, flagVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(flag), (void*) flag, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Code for rendering the VBO:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gameManager->getTextureManager().getTexture("poleEndFlag")); //The get texture method returns 2 which is the correct texture
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, flagVBO);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float)*5, (GLvoid*)3);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float)*5, (GLvoid*)0);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, sizeof(flag) / sizeof(float) / 5);
glFlush();

glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

flagVBO array:

```
flag[120] = {
    //Bottom
    -0.1, 1.4, 0.025, 1, 1,
    -0.8, 1.4, 0.025, 0, 1,
    -0.8, 1.4, -0.025, 0, 0,
    -0.1, 1.4, -0.025, 1, 0,
    //Top
    -0.1, 1.95, 0.025, 1, 1,
    -0.8, 1.95, 0.025, 0, 1,
    -0.8, 1.95, -0.025, 0, 0,
    -0.1, 1.95, -0.025, 1, 0,
    //Front
    -0.1, 1.4, 0.025, 1, 0,
    -0.8, 1.4, 0.025, 0, 0,
    -0.8, 1.95, 0.025, 0, 1,
    -0.1, 1.95, 0.025, 1, 1,
    //Back
    -0.1, 1.4, -0.025, 1, 0,
    -0.8, 1.4, -0.025, 0, 0,
    -0.8, 1.95, -0.025, 0, 1,
    -0.1, 1.95, -0.025, 1, 1,
    //Left
    -0.8, 1.95, 0.025, 1, 1,
    -0.8, 1.4, 0.025, 0, 1,
    -0.8, 1.4, -0.025, 0, 0,
    -0.8, 1.95, -0.025, 1, 0,
    //Right
    -0.1, 1.95, 0.025, 1, 1,
    -0.1, 1.4, 0.025, 0, 1,
    -0.1, 1.4, -0.025, 0, 0,
    -0.1, 1.95, -0.025, 1, 0
}
```

It appears the vertex co-ordinates render correctly but the tex co-ordinates don't. The object is rendered the same color as the main color in the texture but the whole texture is not there.

[image: The image shows the rendered object on the left and the texture it should have on the right]

The image shows the rendered object on the left and the texture it should have on the right

Comment: Are you loading the image into texture with `glTexImage2D`?

Comment: Yes I am. Im fairly sure the texture is loaded correctly because the object always appears as the main color from what ever texture I attempt to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your texture coord pointer is wrong. The offset is in *bytes*. And the 3 bytes your are specifying are somewhere inbetween the x and y coordinate of your vertex positions. The correct value would be

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float)*5, (GLvoid*) (3*sizeof(GLfloat)) );
```